# Why do I get an XamlParseException with the inner Exception FileNotFoundException when creating Custom Dependency Properties and Controls in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, dependency-properties, data-binding

I am creating custom self-validating TextBoxes (for example a *PathRestrictedTextBox*), which I am using inside of Custom Controls (a *PathRestrictedTextBox* might be combined with a search Button and beeing usable as *UcPathBox*).

However I have created such classes.

My *UcPathBox* uses the *PathRestrictedTextBox* as follows:

```
    <controls:PathRestrictedTextBox x:Name="_tbxPathTextBox" Text="{Binding Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
    <Button Content="..." HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="DialogClick" />
```

> The declaration of the Binding to the Text Property causes an
>   XamlParseException with an inner FileNotFound Exception.

*Value* is a Dependency Property defined in the codebehind of *UcPathBox*:

```
    public static DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(string), typeof(UcPathBox), new PropertyMetadata("default"));
    public string Value
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)GetValue(ValueProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
        }
    }
```

Thats where my latin's finished, first of all, because I have been trying this just before in a small version with the same Binding Declaration and Dependency Propertie registration - And therefore it worked..

Because I may not see any difference I am asking here.

EDIT:
It seems not to find the WPFToolkit.. (that's what it says inside the FileNotFoundException) but the reference is added correctly and all my other bindings do work.

EDIT2:
I somehow managed not tho use my Toolkit. why It didn't find the Assembly is still a mistery, but it doesn't bother me anymore :)

If I find it out sometime I tell you. And I make a new self-answered Question.

**Anyway thanks alot**

Comment: Do you know, for which file it is raising `FileNotFoundException`?

Comment: @sthotakura the FileName is "WPFToolkit, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"

Comment: Maybe, WPFToolkit not being copied to the target folder? Did you check if WPFToolkit assembly exists in the bin folder?

Comment: @sthotakura you were right, its not copied, although its Copy Local Property is set to true. What I may not get is why my Windows do work if the dll is not copied - and how to fix it, because normally adding the reference fixes my problem.

Comment: @sthotakura In my little tryout that **is** working, there is also no wpftoolkit assembly in the bin folder.